# /index.html: better to use no-store or no-cache for cache-control?

Tags: web-server, amazon-cloudfront

When the root page is subject to frequent invalidation, like a news feed, do you generally prefer `no-store` or `no-cache` in the response header of cache-control? One advantage of `no-store` - from what I can tell - is that it spares the browser from even making the pre-flight request to determine if local version is stale. Is no-store well supported?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The badly named `no-cache` doesn’t mean not to cache, but actually means “cache, but do not use without checking it’s still valid”. It is typically used for non-sensitive pages that will change often - like your example of a newspaper home page.

Whereas `no-store` means “don’t cache it at all”. It is typically used for sensitive pages (e.g. internet banking pages).

And finally the, also badly named, `must revalidate max-age=XXXX` means “use without revalidating this up until `XXXX` seconds have passed and then check with server before reusing it (i.e. treat it as `no-cache`)”. It is used for cacheable resources (whether for short times, long times or somewhere in between).

> from what I can tell - is that [no-store] spares the browser from even making the pre-flight request to determine if local version is stale.

I think you’re misunderstanding this. It does make **an additional** pre-flight request. `No-cache` makes a request for the resource but also says “hey I have a version already let me know if that’s still valid”. If it’s still valid it gets a shorter response (304 Not Modified) if it’s not still valid it gets the full response back - just like it would with `no-store`. So there is no additional request, it’s just that `no-cache` might save you from re-downloading the whole resource again if it has not changed. Which is a good thing as it saves bandwidth for the client and the server. It’s pointless to re-download something of you already have it. Therefore you should always prefer `no-cache` over `no-store` for non-sensitive pages.

> Is no-store well supported?

All of them are well supported by all browsers. Though it should be noted that browsers often will reuse the page on certain navigation, which can be unexpected. So going back will reuse the page even if no-cache or no-store is specified, which does confuse people. Other navigation (e.g. going to another site and then back, or just visiting a link or a URL) **will** cause a revalidation with the server as expected.